# Custom menus outside Addon menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I am working on Google sheets Addon and want to create custom menu outside Addon menu something like below:

**Expected output**

[image]

**Actual output**

[image]

I found that it only works for Container-bound Scripts but not for Addon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/menus), this is only possible for unpublished add-ons, but even when testing the add-on, the top-level menus gets moved into the Add-ons menu.

> Caution: Unpublished add-ons can also create custom top-level menus, but these are automatically moved under the Add-ons menu if the add-on is published and may not result in the user experience you intended. If you intend to publish the add-on, always use Ui.createAddonMenu() to define the add-on menu.