# Standalone script won't add custom menus

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, menu, add-on

Following the [Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) as well as the documentation on [createMenu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#createmenucaption) and [addMenu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addMenu(String,Object)), I'm trying to add a custom menu to my Spreadsheet, like so:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
   .createMenu('Test Menu')
   .addItem('foo', 'bar')
   .addToUi();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   .addMenu('Test Menu 2', [{ name: 'foo', functionName: 'bar' }]);
}
```

I wrote this as a standalone Apps Script project, and I'm deploying it via a Test Deployment from the Deploy drop down: Deploy -> Test Deployments -> Add test -> Installed and Enabled, selected a Spreadsheet file in my Google Drive. When I then click on Execute, the Spreadsheet opens, but the menus don't show. There is no error in the log. What gives?

[image]
[image]

I know that adding menus requires binding the script to a document, and I'm *assuming* that associating the file in the Test Deployment dialog does that. For what it's worth, the bound script methods like `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` didn't throw exceptions, so I assume the binding worked.

I have not modified the `appscript.json` file from its defaults. In another test I tried adding OAuth scopes for spreadsheets, but that didn't make a difference in the behavior described in this post.

Comment: Please read in your first reference `A script can only create a menu if it is bound to the document, spreadsheet, or form. ` A standalone script means it does not have a container

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper. This reference, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons says editor add-ons are developed as stand-along scrips and can add custom menus. This reference validates that testing procedure is sound: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons . I think not all docs are necessarily correctly cross-referenced for all edge cases which is what makes this hard.

Comment: This one: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: Globals. Show code outside any function

Comment: Also, Have you checked the "Add ons" menu?

Comment: @Cooper The menus get moved to a sub item  under "Addons", when testing. See that question's two images.

Comment: The link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60201017/custom-menus-outside-addon-menu was helpful. In the meantime I had discovered my menu under the Extension tab as well. In fact, apparently standalone add-on scripts are encouraged to only use `createAddonMenu` and not `createMenu`. The `addMenu` function seems to be a silent no-op.  This reference was useful: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/menus